# Using atan2() in Swift Playground - Xcode 9

Tags: swift, trigonometry

I'm very new to Swift, so I apologize if I'm missing something very obvious. I did do a lot of searching and didn't find anything relevant to my problem.

I'm trying to figure out how to call atan() or atan2() in Swift to create a latitude/longitude distance calculator in Playground.

Simply:

```
distanceCarryFormula = 2 * atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
```

I keep finding references saying that atan() is included in Xcode's default library for my version of Xcode, but I can't find it.

I found some documentation from Apple on how to create an atan() function but there were no parameters in the function.
([Apple's example referenced core graphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455332-atan2), so maybe not available in playgrounds?

```
func atan2(_ lhs: CGFloat, _ rhs: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

What am I missing here? Is atan() just not available in playgrounds, or what should I be doing?

How can I use atan() or atan2() in playgrounds?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm able to use it from both iOS and Mac playgrounds.  Make sure you're using "import Foundation" at a minimum.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't include a posted answer in your question, just vote them up and accept them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you `import Foundation` at the top of your playground.  Note that `UIKit` implicitly imports Foundation.

As pointed out by vacawama, it's actually part of Darwin, so `import Darwin` would work, but Foundation, UIKit, or AppKit all implicitly include Darwin and are normally included in your Playground.

Comment: I think the minimum is `import Darwin`.

Comment: Looks like it, but nobody every imports that alone :)

Comment: I had deleted import Foundation from my playgrounds file for other reasons earlier. This fixed it - thank you!